# Execute steps process using ionicLoading and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-promise

I need to execute some steps in my controller (on load). I want select data in a local SQLite database and if not exists, do a request in my webservice. All of this with loading indicator. I'm using Ionic Framework and AngularJS.

My actual code doesn't show the progress and inverts the order that data are retrieved (Funcionarios before Empresas).

**Controller:**

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.loaded', function () {
    $ionicLoading.show({
        template: 'loading'
    })

    //search in local database
    RepositorioEmpresas.obterTodos().then(function (empresas) {
        $scope.empresas = empresas;           

        if ($scope.empresas.length == 0) {
            //request to webservice
            ServicoEmpresas.obterEmpresas($rootScope.idSupervisor).then(function (response) {

                if (response.status == 1) {
                    $scope.empresas = response.dados;

                    //add data retrieve in local database
                    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.empresas.length; i++) {
                        RepositorioEmpresas.adicionar($scope.empresas[i]);
                    }                        
                }
            }, function (e) {
                Mensagem.alerta('error');
                $ionicLoading.hide();
            });
        }

        $rootScope.empresas = $scope.empresas;
    });

    //similar to the previous
    RepositorioFuncionarios.obterTodos().then(function (funcionarios) {
        var funcionariosTemp = funcionarios;            

        if (funcionariosTemp.length == 0) {
            ServicoFuncionarios.obterFuncionarios($rootScope.idSupervisor).then(function (response) {

                if (response.status == 1) {
                    funcionariosTemp = response.dados;

                    RepositorioFuncionarios.removerTodos();

                    for (var i = 0; i < funcionariosTemp.length; i++) {
                        RepositorioFuncionarios.adicionar(funcionariosTemp[i]);
                    }                       
                }
            }, function (e) {
                Mensagem.alerta('error.');
                $ionicLoading.hide();
            });
        }           
    });                    

    $ionicLoading.hide();
})
```

**Services**

```
.factory('ServicoFuncionarios', function ($http, $q) {
    const url = 'url';
    var self = this;
    var retorno = [];

    self.obterFuncionarios = function (idSupervisor) {
        var q = $q.defer();

        $http.get(url + '&idSupervisor=' + idSupervisor, { timeout: 5000 })
            .success(function (resposta) {
                q.resolve(resposta);
            })
            .error(function (e) {
                q.reject('erro na consulta ao webservice' + e);
            });

        return q.promise;
    }

    return self;
})

.factory('RepositorioFuncionarios', function (Repositorio) {
    var self = this;

    self.obterTodos = function () {
        return Repositorio.query("SELECT id, idEmpresa, nome, cpf FROM funcionarios")
            .then(function (resultado) {
                return Repositorio.obterTodos(resultado)
            });
    }

    self.adicionar = function (funcionario) {
        var campos = [funcionario.id, funcionario.idEmpresa, funcionario.nome, funcionario.cpf];
        return Repositorio.query("INSERT INTO funcionarios (id, idEmpresa, nome, cpf) VALUES (?,?,?,?)", campos);
    }

    self.removerTodos = function () {
        return Repositorio.query("DELETE FROM funcionarios");
    }

    return self;
})
```

**Code updated**

After the excellent answer, I adjusted the code. I need now execute ServicoEmpresas and ServicoFuncionarios only if RepositorioEmpresas and RepositorioFuncionarios don't return data (in some cases, the http request is not necessary). How can I control conditional promises?

```
$ionicLoading.show({
        content: 'Atualizando lista de usuários',
        animation: 'fade-in',
        showBackdrop: true,
        maxWidth: 200,
        showDelay: 0
    })

    RepositorioEmpresas.obterTodos().then(function (empresas) {
        $scope.empresas = empresas;
        console.log('Empresas carregadas!');

        if ($scope.empresas.length == 0) {
            return ServicoEmpresas.obterEmpresas($rootScope.idSupervisor)
        }

        $rootScope.empresas = $scope.empresas;
    }).then(function (response) {
        if (response.status == 1) {
            $scope.empresas = response.dados;

            RepositorioEmpresas.removerTodos();

            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.empresas.length; i++) {
                RepositorioEmpresas.adicionar($scope.empresas[i]);
            }
            console.log('Empresas consultadas!');

            $rootScope.empresas = $scope.empresas;
        }
    }).then(function () {
        return RepositorioFuncionarios.obterTodos();
    }).then(function (funcionarios) {
        var funcionariosTemp = funcionarios;
        console.log('Funcionários carregados!');

        if (funcionariosTemp.length == 0) {
            return ServicoFuncionarios.obterFuncionarios($rootScope.idSupervisor);
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        if (response.status == 1) {
            funcionariosTemp = response.dados;

            RepositorioFuncionarios.removerTodos();

            for (var i = 0; i < funcionariosTemp.length; i++) {
                RepositorioFuncionarios.adicionar(funcionariosTemp[i]);
            }
            console.log('Funcionários consultados!');
        }
    }).catch(function (e) {
        Mensagem.alerta('Falha na consulta dos dados.');
    }).finally(function () {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not [chaining](https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/angularjs-promises) the 2 promises.
They're resolved independently so you do not have any guarantee on which is executed before the other.

The [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service already returns a promise so you could avoid doing this:

```
var q = $q.defer();

$http.get(url + '&idSupervisor=' + idSupervisor, { timeout: 5000 })
       .success(function (resposta) {
       q.resolve(resposta);
    })
    .error(function (e) {
       q.reject('erro na consulta ao webservice' + e);
    });

return q.promise;
```

but simply:

```
return $http.get(url + '&idSupervisor=' + idSupervisor, { timeout: 5000 });
```

$q promises are chained using the `.then()` if they are [resolved](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises) or `.catch()` if there's an error.

Your code should do something like this:

```
RepositorioEmpresas.obterTodos()
    .then(function (empresas) {
        return ServicoEmpresas.obterEmpresas($rootScope.idSupervisor);
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        if (response.status == 1) {
            $scope.empresas = response.dados;

            //add data retrieve in local database
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.empresas.length; i++) {
                RepositorioEmpresas.adicionar($scope.empresas[i]);
            }                        
                }       
    })
    .then(function (){
        return RepositorioFuncionarios.obterTodos();
    })
    .then(function (funcionarios){

    })
    .catch(function(reason() {
        // reason contains your error.
    });
```

As you can see in each `.then()` we call a function/method which resolves a promise and use the return so we can used the returned value (when the promise is resolve) to the next `.then()`:

```
.then(function (empresas) {
    return ServicoEmpresas.obterEmpresas($rootScope.idSupervisor);
})
.then(function (response) {
    // response is the returned value of ServicoEmpresas.obterEmpresas
})
```

The way you've done things causes the problem with the `$ionicLoading` service as well, since you're calling `$ionicLoading.hide();` at the very bottom. This command will be executed immediately right before the execution of the promises, which will be resolved when they `$http` service returns a result.

You can use the `.finally()` to do some clean-up:

```
myPromise()
    .then(function (result) {
        return myOtherPromise();
    })
    .then(function (result) {
        // do something with the final result.
    })
    .catch(function (reason) {
        // reason contains your error.
    })
    .finally(function(){
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    });
```

Another option is to use interceptors:

```
app.config(function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($rootScope) {
    return {
      request: function(config) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:show')
        return config
      },
      response: function(response) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:hide')
        return response
      }
    }
  })
})
```

which will trigger events and the events themselves will be intercepted in the `$rootScope`:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $ionicLoading) {
  $rootScope.$on('loading:show', function() {
    $ionicLoading.show({template: 'foo'})
  })

  $rootScope.$on('loading:hide', function() {
    $ionicLoading.hide()
  })
})
```

this way you've managed to show/hide the loading indicator every time a long-running http request is executed.

Explanation [here](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/loading-screen-with-interceptors/).

Comment: Perfect answer! You resolved all of my doubts about this. Thanks a lot! I have only a question about conditional promises (I updated the question).

Comment: You can check the returned data. If there's no data you can simply `return true;` or `return;` and the chain will go to the next branch. Once you're in the chain you can return a sync or an async result (promise) and the chain will be respected. There's an [article](http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html) - which I consider the best on promises - which is worth reading. It's hard to grasp at the beginning but make all things clear after a while. Have a look at **Rookie mistake #5**. Cheers.

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if you're happy with it. Thanks.